# Use a web content portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using web content portlet to develop a portal.

Each page has common theme (which includes header and footer) and we have many portlets placed on each page.

One of the portlet on right side is menu which is common on many pages.

I could have kept it as a part of theme but the menu can be subject to change in future and the end user who will be handling the portal is non-developer. 
So if they want to change some data in that menu portlet, they will have to change it on every page which leads to duplication of effort.

Like I said, since end user is a non-developer, I cannot make that portlet part of the theme.

So is there any way where one web content portlet be created once and used on many pages?

Comment: You need to create a single web content and use that web content on different page using web content display

Comment: @LuckyBoy : I am using Liferay 6.2 When I click on add Web Content Display everytime, a new blank web content portlet is created on the page.
How to use an existing one? I am not creating portlets using eclipse. I need to create Web content displays and reuse them since end user will be non developer

Answer (score 0):

You can embed web-content in theme as per [link](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/24879333)

Here articleId as in above link, you can set in theme-setting, refer to [link](http://pmkathiria.blogspot.in/2014/01/dynamic-customization-in-theme-via.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution right now. If anyone has abetter solution than this..they are most welcome. I would like people to share alternate and better solutions

I am using Liferay 6.2

What I did was added a new web content display portlet which like I said created a new blank web content display portlet.
So my usual method was to add content to this portlet. THis was the method I followed. You can click on Select Web Content button and then select the already created portal from the list and you are done. NO need to create duplicate portlets

Comment: I was talking about this method. But demerit of this method is you need to select web content for every page.(If I understand correctly your approach)

Comment: @LuckyBoy : Yes. Demerit is I will have to select for every page. BUt right now approach seems fine. Thanks for the lead.